# Resolve all async promises with validate.js

Tags: node.js, promise, validate.js

I'm using this library for validation: https://validatejs.org/#validate-async.

I've got a fairly complicated way of validating nested objects against their own schema. See the relevant code below.

Basically, it will:

1. Create an async promise for each nested object.
2. Then call Promise.all to resolve or reject the validations.

It's working well, except one problem. With the default promise library `Promise.all` "fails fast" so in the catch handler, which is in later express middleware, it only receives results from the first failed promise. But for my validators to work I need to combine the results from all the failed promises.

Is there an alternative promise library (A+ compliant) that I could swap into the validator that would allow me to capture all errors?

```
ValidationAdapter.prototype.validateCreateCtrl = function(req, res, next){
  var obj = {};
  var self = this;
  this.logger.debug("Validating " + self.config.modelName + " create request");
  self.fieldList.forEach(function(fieldName){
    obj[fieldName] = req.body[fieldName];
  });

  self._resolveObjectRefs(obj);

  this.logger.debug("Composed request object " + JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));

  var Promises = [];
  Promises.push(validate.async(obj, self.constraints));

  Object.keys(self.embeddedConstraints).forEach(function (key){
    var value = obj[key];
    var constraints = self.embeddedConstraints[key];
    if (value.constructor === Array){
      var i = 0;
      value.forEach(function(newVal){
        Promises.push(validate.async(newVal, constraints, {path: key + "[" + i + "]."}));
        i++;
      });
    }else{
      Promises.push(validate.async(value, constraints, {path: key}))
    }
  });

  // by default it should fall through
  Promise.all(Promises).then(function(){
    return next();
  }).catch(next);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the bluebird's reflect to implement `settleAll`:

```
Promise.all(Promises.map(function(promise) {
    return promise.reflect();
})).each(function(inspection) {
    if (inspection.isFulfilled()) {
        console.log("Success...");
    } else {
        console.error("Reject...");
    }
});
```

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/reflect.html#reflect